# How can i get the second column of all rows that have selected checkbox in datatables even from other pages

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc, checkbox, datatables

I have this table (generated data from controller spring mvc and thymeleaf object).
I want to choose data from multiple pages of my datatable.
And get all values of second columns selected checkboxes (as you see in the table it is named 'ID').
How can i do that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var mytable = $("#maliste").DataTable({
            'columnDefs': [
                 {
                    'targets': 0,
                    className: 'select-checkbox',
                    'checkboxes': {
                       'selectRow': true
                    }
                 }
              ],

              'select': {
                 'style': 'multi'
              },
              'order': [[1, 'asc']],
              fixedHeader: true,
                searching : true,
                deferRender: true,
                paging : true,
                bProcessing : true,

                dom : 'iftlrp'
        });



        $('#selection').click( function () {

            //i want to have informations here 
        } );
```

Here is html table :

```
<p><button id="selection"  class="btn btn-danger"> THIS IS BUTTON TO GET SELECTION</button> <br></p>
        <table id="maliste" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th><!--  FOR CHECKBOXES -->
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>STRUCTURE</th>
                <th>CLIENT</th>
                <th>ANNEE</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr th:each="boite : ${liste}">
                <td ></td>
                <td th:text="${boite.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${boite.structure}"></td>
                <td th:text="${boite.client}"></td>
                <td th:text="${boite.annee}" style="white-space: pre-line"></td>
            </tr>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th><!--  FOR CHECKBOXES -->
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>STRUCTURE</th>
                <th>CLIENT</th>
                <th>ANNEE</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Here it is the page how it looks, i want when i click on the button to get list of ids and send to controller form exemple to localhost:8080/send_ids 
[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataTables api to retrieve the selected row data.

See https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html

And https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/select.html

```js
var mytable = $('#maliste').DataTable({ ... });

$('#selection').on('click', function() {
   // Get selection
   var selectedRows = mytable.rows({ selected: true });

   // Get selection column data
   var selectedData = selectedRows.data();

   // Get 2nd column values
   var selectedIDs = $.map(selectedData, function(row) {
       return row[ 1 ];
   });

   console.log(selectedIDs);
});
```

This will print an array of values from the 2nd column.

Check out my working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3ew1go6p/

Comment: It works for me, i have juste to import the js and css files